# Authentication cookie expiration

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, cookies, forms-authentication

I have two asp.net mvc running web sites (Server1 and Server 2). The files under these sites are all same. Mirrored manually.

**Problem :**

On the Server1, after creating asp.net authenticate ticket, cookie expires after a period of time automatically. But on the other server (Server2) cookie still exist.

ASP.NET MVC platform on IIS 6.0. They are on the same server but different IP's

Server1: http://www.seniseviyorum.com/WebForm1.aspx
Server2: http://www.snsvyrm.com/WebForm1.aspx

Any idea?

```
GET /WebForm1.aspx HTTP/1.1
Host: www.seniseviyorum.com
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:8.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/8.0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: en-us,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7
Connection: keep-alive
Referer: http://www.seniseviyorum.com/WebForm1.aspx
Cookie: .SSAUTHSS=83E0F44BB68931FACD95B3F64FF2073738C629A0EEFE9D89657E8C457E54888584248D3CE0AF000C90C0E59A073D5BA4DC12C12F930EFF8CF9C712F413825A814ABE278702C0943D70C1771543487CC7E075990D8795B904194799D0E3E1349A6F6518350395A91F7E100C574D03CB136E4C9FAD52C8CE1F37F95AB0014A75B9E0F7C875910126E4B0A1C51F1058C08E; __utma=88980377.776610536.1325205796.1325205796.1325205796.1; __utmc=88980377; __utmz=88980377.1325205796.1.1.utmcsr=(direct)|utmccn=(direct)|utmcmd=(none)
Cache-Control: max-age=0
```

---

```
GET /WebForm1.aspx HTTP/1.1
Host: www.snsvyrm.com
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:8.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/8.0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: en-us,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7
Connection: keep-alive
Referer: http://www.snsvyrm.com/WebForm1.aspx
Cookie: .SSAUTHSS=182C451AC2F9E07E25EBDC5CFDE50BDD04C39C045FD86A9868283198C3401AACAB8D52B026380109E162C82266D221FB52EFFA09B08D643086D3C9D7B3DC8D273B69F97A1C0899A5935492BCDCF2CA7723F8E9E470F3D9D72613787D3C2701B0F51CFCAB77BB7A729A2171739BD6A547BA95026CF3E9B2E5593024B57E80C8DF15760EB5CB5A459F547025F862C5C3FB; __utma=92513119.1344156904.1325205837.1325205837.1325208669.2; __utmc=92513119; __utmz=92513119.1325205837.1.1.utmcsr=(direct)|utmccn=(direct)|utmcmd=(none)
Cache-Control: max-age=0
```

Comment: Can you post the response headers from each server (using Firebug or similar)? I don't have it installed on my current machine.

Comment: This may seem like the obvious question, but are you using the same browser to access both IPs?

Comment: James, Response headers are same. I put Request headers

Comment: Do both applications belong to the same AppPool? (Sorry been out of web dev for a while)

Comment: Do you expect the cookie to be the same for both servers? Then read the answer of epignosisx. Or is the problem that a cookie on server 2 never times out?

Comment: Problem is that:On Server1 Cookie expires before expiration date. On the other hand On server2 It seems normal. They are both using same application pool

Answer (score 1):

Authentication tokens are sent back and forth between the server and browser using a cookie. Since each website uses a different domain, each will have its own authentication cookie. They will not share the same cookie. So it's perfectly normal that one of them expires after certain amount of time without making an http request to the server.

Comment: I think so. Maybe I misunderstood :\

Comment: I also could have misunderstood, but I read it as though they *weren't* expecting the cookie from one domain to be valid in the other. It doesn't say that anywhere in the question anyway. If I misunderstood then this is a good answer!

Comment: I am not expecting to share cookies :)